# Is it necessary to have a unique clientUserId property for every request?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the Embedded Signing API. The prototype is working great !! 
Thanks for the examples.

My question is -  Is it necessary to have a unique clientUserId property for every request that is made ? Does it have to stored in the database? I have read the api documents and they all mention something along these lines :

```
if the clientUserId is present and it's value is not null then the recipient is an embedded recipient, and they can access the envelope through a URL token instead of a hyperlink in an email.
```

In my code 'clientUserId' is hardcoded to 1 while creating an envelope and has the same value when getting an url for launching the embedded signing view (aka recipient view).

Is that okay or do I have to generate a unique clientUserId for every request and store it in a database ?

Thanks

Comment: If you provide the same email@/name/clientUserID triplet, then the signer does not have to re-adopt their signature - DocuSign will be able to identify the signer and leverage their previously adopted signature. The clientUserID should be something meaningful and unique within your organization to identify the signer/customer.

Answer (score 0):

*Posting Luis' comment as it should be an answer...*

If you provide the same (`email`, `name`, `clientUserID`) triplet, then the signer does not have to re-adopt their signature - DocuSign will be able to identify the signer and leverage their previously adopted signature. Otherwise, the signer will have to draw in their signature at every signature/initial here tab assigned to them in the envelope.

Generally speaking the clientUserID should be something meaningful and unique within your organization to identify the signer/customer; however it's still ok to use simple values as you have mentioned if your specific use-case does not call for further granulation/definition of signers, and you don't mind having them to explicitly sign each time.